# Outputting Images in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: image, scipy, ipython, jupyter

The following code is able to print/output images as intended in a Jupyter notebook:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
from IPython import display
from scipy.misc import toimage
import numpy as np

n = 3
for _ in range(n):
    (toimage(np.random.rand(32, 32, 3)))
    print("----------------------------")
```

However, once I put it inside a function, it stops working. Why? And how can I fix it?

```
def print_images(n=3):
    for _ in range(n):
        (toimage(np.random.rand(32, 32, 3)))
        print("----------------------------")

print_images()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display.display_png` works:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
from IPython import display
from scipy.misc import toimage
import numpy as np

n = 3
for _ in range(n):
    display.display_png(toimage(np.random.rand(32, 32, 3)))
    print("----------------------------")

def print_images(n=3):
    for _ in range(n):
        display.display_png(toimage(np.random.rand(32, 32, 3)))
        print("----------------------------")

print_images()
```

You can read up more on why this works and the other way fails in the [docs for IPython's `display` module](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html).

## Details

The object returned by `toimage` has a `_repr_png_` method. This is what gets called by the notebook to produce the image that you actually see. For whatever reason (which I'm sure you could uncover by digging into the docs), the notebook will call `x._repr_png_()` automatically whenever a call to `toimage` produces any instance `x` in the top scope of a cell. However, if `toimage` is run in a more deeply nested scope, `_repr_png_` is not automatically called. Instead, you have to manually engage that same display machinery with an explicit call to `display.display_png`.

Comment: I used this to write a function for machine learning on images and I hate it when I cannot do functional programming. But now I can, thanks to you.